# Upper bound on a sequence after a finite number of steps

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, nonlinear-system, finite-differences

i need to find an upper bound (as tightest as possible) of the following recurrence for $\mu^{(j)}$

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l} t^{(j-1)} = 2 \mu^{(j-1)} - \nu & j \geq 1\\
\mu^{(j)} = \begin{cases} t^{(j-1)} & \mbox{if } t^{(j-1)} \geq 0  \\ 2 \mu^{(j-1)} & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases} & j\geq 1 \\
\nu \in  \left( 2^{mw} , 2^{mw + 1} \right) \cap \mathbb{Z} \\
\mu^{(0)} = 2^{mw + 1} - \nu
\end{array} \right.$$

You can assume $mw$ is integer and $\geq 4$.

Here's my attempt,
assuming that $t^{(k)} \geq 0$ for each $k$ then

$$\mu^{(j)} = 2 \mu^{(j-1)} - \nu \Rightarrow \Delta \mu^{(j-1)} = \mu^{(j-1)} - \nu$$

Assuming i solved correctly the difference equation i derived

$$\mu^{(j)} = C \times 2^{j} + \nu$$

Where $C$ is a constant that depends from the initial condition $\mu^{(0)} = 2^{mw + 1} - \nu$.

However the bound is too large, so basically my second attempt was to find a kind of "invariant" between a step that goes between the step $t^{(j-1)} < 0$ and $t^{(j)} \geq 0$ and then use it to prove a bound.

I specifically need a bound for $j = mw + 1$

Any clue?

Comment: This describes simultaneously two very different dynamical systems, the first one on $(0,\nu)$, chaotic, and the second one on $(\nu,+\infty)$, trivial. What is the sign of $\mu^{(0)}-\nu$?

Comment: OK, so actually $\mu^{(0)}>\nu$, then $\mu^{(j)}=\nu+2^j(\mu^{(0)}-\nu)$ for every $j$ and the dynamics is simply $\mu\to2\mu-\nu$ (the part I described as trivial previously).

Comment: Could you elaborate? you're too fast, i don't understand the "simply".

Comment: Well, if $\mu^{(j)}>\nu$ then $\mu^{(j+1)}>\nu$ hence, if $\mu^{(0)}>\nu$ then $\mu^{(j)}>\nu$ for every $j$ and one can altogether forget the subtlety of the dynamics which says that if $\mu^{(j)}<\frac12\nu$ then $\mu^{(j+1)}=2\mu^{(j)}$ instead of $\mu^{(j+1)}=2\mu^{(j)}-\nu$.

Comment: I don't see any consideration about the $t^{(j)}$, that's the problem.

Comment: No need to, as already explained the dynamics is $\mu\to2\mu-\nu$ ad infinitum.

Comment: (i have to change my question probably), ok i got you're point (you basically have studied the system asymptotically) however what i do actually need is to prove a bound after for $j = mw + 1$, this is why i was using the induction etc.

Comment: Please read: **There is nothing asymptotic here**, if $\mu^{(0)}\gt\nu$ then the dynamics is $\mu\to2\mu-\nu$ **at every step** hence $\mu^{(j)}=\nu+2^j(\mu^{(0)}-\nu)$ **for every finite** $j$.

Comment: But is this equivalent to say that $t^{(j)}$ is never negative?

Comment: ?? You know that $\mu^{(j)}>\nu$ with $\nu>0$ and you ask whether $t^{(j)}=2\mu^{(j)}-\nu$ is such that $t^{(j)}>0$? Surely you can solve this mystery!

Comment: No, i mean that. I know that $\mu^{(j)} > \nu$, then i compute $t^{(j)}$ if $t^{(j)}$ is negative then $\mu^{(j+1)} = 2 \mu^{(j)}$ otherwise is $\mu^{(j+1)} = 2 \mu^{(j)} - \nu$ is this equivalent to the system i've written above?

Comment: But $t^{(j)}$ is never negative (for the reason already explained at least twice).

Comment: The issue is that system is derived by an algorithm and discussing with you i'm having a doubt that i derived the system in the wrong way.

Comment: I changed the initial condition on $\mu^{(0)}$, i'm not sure that would change that much.

Comment: This changes everything. You might want to draw the graph of the function $g$ defined by $g(\mu)=2\mu$ if $\mu$ is in $(0,\nu/2)$ and $g(\mu)=2\mu-\nu$ if $\mu$ is in $(\nu/2,+\infty)$, to see that what happens when $\mu^{(0)}$ is in $(0,\nu)$ is complicated.